# Should I run 2 firewalls or manage everything from one?

Tags: networking, firewall, unifi, opnsense

I currently have a UniFI Firewall in place and I plan to get a OPNsense firewall mainly for a VPN.

Setup:
Modem - OPNsense Firewall - UniFI Firewall - VLANS (Rules made by UniFi)

Are there any advantages of running a setup with 2 firewalls or should I move everything to the new (more powerful) OPNsense firewall?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save yourself the headaches and sparing the additional Single Point Failure and just combine onto the more powerful hardware.

The only time I would multi firewall setup if you needed to segregate for "sub" networks. Say to make X rules for workstations but Y rules for servers.